# Creating a delete trigger with archive table for records and all of its related records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I need to create a deleting trigger with archive table so when I delete a record from one table it  goes into archive table plus its related records from other tables in SQL.

I have 4 tables called `Songs`, `Genres`, `Performers` and `Directors` plus relations which are `SongPerformers` connecting `Songs` and `Performers`, relation `SongGenres` connecting `Songs` and `Genres` and `SongDirectors` connecting `Songs` and `Directors`.

I created the delete trigger for the `Songs` table and archive table too. The problem is that when deleting from the `Songs` table, the records that are deleted are just in `Songs` table but doesn't delete the related records from other tables.

Here is the database diagram of how the database looks and the trigger I created:

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF22I.png)

Trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE Archives
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    SongTitle VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    SongReleaseDate date NOT NULL,
    SongTime float NOT NULL,
    SongLanguage VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Date DATETIME NOT NULL
)

CREATE TRIGGER Archivetrigger
ON Songs
AFTER DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO Archives (SongTitle, SongReleaseDate, SongTime, SongLanguage, [Date])
        SELECT 
            d.SongTitle, d.SongReleaseDate, d.SongTime, d.SongLanguage, GETDATE()
        FROM 
            deleted d



DELETE FROM Songs
WHERE SongID = 1

SELECT * FROM Archives
```

Like how can I add the other tables in the trigger so when I delete a record from Songs all of its related records are deleted too and added to the archive table.

Comment: Trigger syntax and how they work can deeply vary according from database to database. What DBMS are you currently using?

Comment: Im using RDBMS, SQl server

Comment: For deleting related records you can select CASCADE option. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1326ef/use-of-cascade-in-sql-server/
But for archiving - you need the trigger on each table

Comment: You'd be much better off using the common pattern where you flag the record as deleted without actually deleting it. It really need to move it then use a stored procedure carry out the move/delete.

Comment: If you really have to use a trigger (should be your last choice) then use an instead off trigger and add the related tables in your trigger above .

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer that works for my case (it's not perfect but it works), all i had to do in the trigger was to add some lines that help delete the related records from the other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Archives
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
SongTitle VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
SongReleaseDate date NOT NULL,
SongTime float NOT NULL,
SongLanguage VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Date DATETIME NOT NULL
)
CREATE TRIGGER Archivetrigger
ON Songs
AFTER delete
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Archives (SongTitle, SongReleaseDate, SongTime, SongLanguage, [Date])
SELECT d.SongTitle, d.SongReleaseDate, d.SongTime,d.SongLanguage,GETDATE()
FROM deleted d
DELETE FROM SongPerformers WHERE SongID = (SELECT TOP 1 SongID FROM deleted)
DELETE FROM SongDirectors WHERE SongID = (SELECT TOP 1 SongID FROM deleted)
DELETE FROM SongGenres WHERE SongID = (SELECT TOP 1 SongID FROM deleted)
END
```

Here is the syntax, it's obviously not perfect, but its close to what i need and works for me:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[*nameoftrigger*]
ON [dbo].[*nameoftable*]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM *tableyoudeletefrom* WHERE *tableID* = (SELECT TOP 1 *tableID* FROM DELETED)
END
```

You can add all the table you need to be deleted from.